# How to improve my code with using module pattern or any other ways?

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

i'm refactoring my JS spaghetti code to something more useful and less chaotic.

I want to get rid out of spaghetti code i have.

At the moment i've got a lot of different functions and events that work with gridster widgets:

```
function applyJsonToGrid()
{
//some code here
}

function insertWidgetToGrid()
{
//some code here
}

$(document).on("click", ".add", function () {
insertWidgetToGrid();
}

// and a lot of different code written in this way
```

I've found this one idea: [example](https://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-structure-javascript-the-module-pattern-edition/)

In my attempts to create own module i've got this:

```
var gridsterModule = {

    settings: {
        gridElement: $('.gridster ul li'),
        gridList: $('.gridster ul')
    },

    init: function () {
        this.simpleTest();
    },


    simpleTest: function () {
        console.log(this.settings.gridList)
    }
}
```

after that i'm trying to test if my module gets right settings:

```
 $(function () {
        gridsterModule.init();
    });
```

But in console i get empty object, instead of my $('.gridster ul'). Am i doing something wrong or i don't understand the idea correctly? There are .gridster ul elements in my html and if i call $('.gridster ul') from the console i get values i need.

Any explanation on how to work with modules and any other ways to improve my JS code would be great!

Comment: You may need to place `var gridsterModule = { ... }` in `$(function () { ... })` to make sure it's created when DOM is loaded

Answer (score 0):

probably you need to setup initial value instead of do this `gridList: $('.gridster ul')`.

try this

```
var gridsterModule = {

    settings: {
        gridElement: null,
        gridList: null
    },

    init: function () {
        this.settings.gridElement = $('.gridster ul li');
        this.settings.gridList = $('.gridster ul');

        this.simpleTest();
    },


    simpleTest: function () {
        console.log(this.settings.gridList)
    }
}
```